# Has there been any mention of withdrawal of maya sarees by Krishna in any version of Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, identification-request, reference-request

It is stated in the video by the Swamiji (as narrated to him by his Guru) Lord Krishna supplied unending sheet lengths of saree at first as a rescue measure in the hour of Draupadi's need when Kauravas tried to shame her in the court. There was a piled up mountain of miles of the finest saree material removed by Duhssasana.

After the rescue (in some guilt removal maneuver?) Dhritharashtra granted a wish to Draupadi who requested him to immediately free the five Pandavas  who were temporarily helpless by virtue of acceptance of conditions of gambling loss.They all walked away free.

Draupadi left the place wearing the earlier normal saree. But the Kaurava ladies as owners of the gain  later on got cut the material into suitable lengths to share among themselves.. ( as may happen even now under similar circumstances).

Krishna realized that the perpetrators of the misdeed were in fact unwittingly rewarded by His own action. So He  decided to withdraw the Maya sarees given in the hour of her need by His maya power once again thus rendering the grown up Kaurava women ( who sat centrally placed to show off their newly gotten dresses) to reappear in their birthday forms.. thus inflicting on Kauravas a  hundred fold retribution.

Has there been any mention of this counteraction by Krishna in any version of Mahabharata?

[Dussasana's action retorted by Krishna](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=daqDexiF1Sc) (Video in Telugu; approx 8 min 10 sec to 9 min 28 sec)

Comment: It's a good question. But you didn't explain it properly. Please edit it.

Comment: Thanks, edited it... Is more explanation needed?

Comment: It's better now. I think you should add one more point which says kaurava's wives didn't raise their voice during the insult but they were happy to see draupadi's insult for that reason Krishna made disappear these sarees, something like this. Add mb, krishna tag also

Comment: That is may be long drawn. The karavees could not themselves be that vengeful towards their cousin sister, especially when in possession of a stock of divine shimmering silk. The matter between men spilled over to the women, and Draupadi was quite sarcastic towards the Pandavas on this count..  Even if some of them witnessed it all from a balcony above meant for seating royal ladies, their voice would not be heard, they would be ignored by the kauravas and so on..This is anyhow happening right before Bhishma's eyes, a common grandfather ineffective, so what of them?. Tagged already by YDS.